# Unity3D: SetParent not working in runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity3D transform.SetParent not working

When the trigger is activated `itemRef` should be a child of `inventory` and `it works` should be logged to the console but instead it logs `it works` to the console and does not make `itemRef` a child of `inventory`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe;
using UnityEngine;

public class pickUp : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject itemRef;
    public Transform inventory;
    public bool equiped = false;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("it works");
        itemRef.transform.SetParent(inventory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your code to verify that:

1. The other collider is the one you are looking for. Otherwise it will just activate for any collider that enters the trigger and can generate a lot of false positives/ irrelevant logs.
2. That itemRef and inventory are non-null

At that point it then makes sense to try this.

```
public GameObject itemRef;
public Transform inventory;
public bool equiped = false;
public GameObject targetObject;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject != targetObject)
    {
        Debug.Log("Object that entered trigger was incorrect");
        return;
    }

    if(itemRef == null || inventory == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("One or both of the objects in the parenting is null.");
        return;
    }

    Debug.Log("it works");
    itemRef.transform.SetParent(inventory);
}
```

Comment: it still does not work

Comment: How are you determining that it is not working? Visually in the game view? Looking at the hierarchy?

If you aren't already, check it in code:

Add this to the last part inside the above block:

`Debug.Log($"{nameof(inventory)} is {((itemRef.transform.parent == inventory)? "now" : "not" )} the parent of {nameof(itemRef)}");`